# 'Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.' in Flash CS5?

Tags: actionscript-3

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at src::Game/onClick()

This is the full error^, however it doesn't give me the error on the timeline, but the output, when the flash game is played. Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/FnjWCQJ8 , the error's in line 35 or 49.

Thank you.

Comment: blue1, blue2, and blue3 are instance names of a symbol that I've linked with Game.as (which the coded file is called), surely they're defined in that way?

Comment: As far as I know you can not access instances like that from inside a class. To access it you have to pass a reference of the object to the class. Or add your class to the stage and access via "stage"

Comment: So how do I pass a reference of the object to the class? (I'm so sorry, I am an amateur at CS5). Thank you!

Comment: If Game is a MovieClip symbol in Flash Pro with blue1, blue2, blue3 instances on the timeline, Flash will instantiate them during construction.  But good catch by @The_asMan - probably what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because blue1,blue2,and blue3 are not defined anywhere.

```
private function onClick(m:MouseEvent):void{
  blue1.startme = true;
  blue2.startme = true;
  blue3.startme = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably line 31 - your stage instance in the Game constructor. Your MovieClip is probably not on the stage yet. Use an ADDED_TO_STAGE event listener, then add listeners to stage on added to stage handlers.

```
/*
 * Constructor.
 */
public function Game()
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
}

protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

    // Listeners.
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _update);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _mouseAction);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseAction);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

    // Helicopter.
    _helicopter = new Helicopter();
    stage.addChild(_helicopter);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your help, but unfortunately it's still giving me the exact same error in the 'output' section when the game is played.